# Does Anyone know how to disperse the objects inside jelly cake like this?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, transparency, soft-body

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to make a jelly cake. But I am stuck in here. Here are my questions:

1. I'm very confused about making the cake-filling part **slightly visible**. (I don't know how to name this effect, sorry) I tried some geometry nodes, like Volume Scatter and Mix Shader... but I failed.

   This is the reference to the jelly cake. I want to make a similar effect like the centre purple part:
   [image]

   This is my work now:
   [image]
2. **Soft Body effect**

   I'm also stuck in applying to Soft Body. After I applied the soft body to my jelly cake, and I started the keyframe, nothing happened or my jelly cake suddenly exploded and then disappeared  (I guess maybe the CPU of my computer can't carry it?)

   After selecting soft body and starting the keyframe (I tried to set the keyframe in animation, but still didn't work like soft body):
   [image]

   The explosion of jelly cake:
   [image]

Thank you for your help!! Looking forward to any suggestions!

Comment: Hello and welcome! I would separate your questions into 2 separate posts. BSE is a Q&A site and 1 question per post works better because other people with a similar problem can find the questions easier. -- Do you use Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: oh I see. I use cycles.

Comment: 1) If you use Cycles you can use *Transmission* to create this effect. Place a distorted object inside of the jelly, e.g. a subdivided cube with a *Subsurface Division* and a *Displacement* modifier (+plus *Magic* texture (below the modifiers tab). Give it a dark color. For the jelly use a *Principled BSDF* node and set *Transmission* to 1, increase the *Transmission Roughness* and the *IOR* if needed. To make it shiny add *Clear Coat* (=1.0) and lower the *Roughness* value: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JQzS.jpg

Comment: 2) You have not shown your settings and the mesh topology. So just a guess: Soft Body physics works best with a clean quad mesh, no large n-gons. Maybe remesh your model but keep it as low-poly as possible. You also need to adjust the goal and stiffness in the soft body settings or it will break when it hits the ground.